# Ansible 'debug' VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED

Tags: ansible

Should be a quick one for you all. Why do I get the error for this playbook?

```yaml
---
- hosts: "{{ target }}"
  become: yes

  vars:
    sysctl_name: "vm.swappiness"
    sysctl_value: "6"

  tasks:
   - name: 'set VM swap setting'
     sysctl:
       name: "{{ sysctl_name }}"
       value: "{{ sysctl_value }}"
     state: present
     register: results
     sysctl_set: true
     reload: true

   - debug:
       var: results.stdout
```

I `register: results` and then try to output it but I get

```
   "results.stdout": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
```

Comment: As you have discovered, the `sysctl` module does not return a `stdout` parameter. Consider changing `var: results.stdout` to `var: results` to see what the return value actually looks like.

Comment: `stdout` as its name might tell, if you are familiar with C, is for what should have gone to the standard output (= displayed on your terminal) if it was not run in an Ansible task. Dedicated Ansible modules do not print to stdout, so there is no stdout property in that dictionary.

Comment: You’ll usually find stdout in command or shell tasks.

Answer (score 0):

For how to debug a result set of a task you may use an approach like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Set VM swap setting
    sysctl:
      name: vm.swappiness
      value: '6'
      state: present
    register: result

  - name: Show var
    debug:
      var: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show var] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  result:
    changed: false
    failed: false

TASK [Show result] ***
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    changed: false
    failed: false
```

**Documentation**

- [`debug` – Print statements during execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#parameters)
- [Return Values - Common `results`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#results)
- [Registering variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables)